# using ASTVisitor for custom queries

Tags: java, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I've got task to do and I even dont know how to start. I need to implement AST parser for queries like that one:

*((book where publish_date > 2000).author)*

In main method it should look like this:

```
Expression ex = new DotExpression(
   new WhereExpression(
      new NameExpression("book"),
      new NameExpression("publish_date") > 2000
   ),
   new NameExpression("author"));
ex.accept(new ASTVisitor());
```

That's only example how to call it. Any advices how to start? Some code examples would be great.

Comment: Well it is obvious from your example that that each piece of your expression will need to be a class for this to work. So I suggest you make a class for Expression, WhereExepression, NameExpression. Then the attributes of that class would be the values that the Expression could take on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A factory for all those classes would be fine:

```
public abstract class Expressions {
    public static DotExpression dot(NameExpression lhs, Expression rhs);
    public static BooleanExpression where(Expression lhs, Expression rhs);
    public static NameExpression name(String name);
    public static BooleanExpression gt(Expression lhs, Expression rhs);
}
```

Usage

```
 static import Expressions.*;

 ... where(gt(name("publish_date"), value(2000)));
```